# sed to insert colon in a mac address

Tags: regex, sed

I have a list of mac addresses in this format:

```
412010000018
412010000026
412010000034
```

I want this output:

```
41:20:10:00:00:18
41:20:10:00:00:26
41:20:10:00:00:34
```

I tried this, but did not work:

```
sed 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1:\2:\3:\4/g' mac_list
```

How should I do it?

Comment: A mac address is in hexadecimal format and not only numerical.

Comment: Once I get to work with basic numeric format, I can add alphabet regex also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the correct `sed` syntax:

```
\{I\}
     matches exactly I sequences (I is a decimal integer;
     for portability, keep it between 0 and 255 inclusive).

\(REGEXP\)
     Groups the inner REGEXP as a whole, this is used for back references.
```

Here is an example command that covers the first 2 fields

```
     sed 's/^\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\).*$/\1:\2:/'
```

The following command can process a complete MAC address and is easy to read:

```
 sed -e 's/^\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/\1_/'  \
     -e 's/_\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/:\1_/' \
     -e 's/_\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/:\1_/' \
     -e 's/_\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/:\1_/' \
     -e 's/_\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/:\1_/' \
     -e 's/_\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/:\1/'
```

Following the idea from a perl solution posted here by @Qtax with global substitutions one can get a shorter solution:

```
 sed -e 's/\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/\1:/g' -e 's/\(.*\):$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 8):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/..\B/&:/g' file
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked for me

```
sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl example:

```
perl -pe 's/(\b|\G)[\da-f]{2}(?=[\da-f]{2})/$&:/ig' file
```

If the file only has MAC addresses, it could be simplified to:

```
perl -pe 's/\w{2}\B/$&:/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is an acceptable solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS= "" }
{ for (i=1; i<=length($0) ; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) { macaddr=macaddr $i ":" } 
      else { macaddr = macaddr $i }
  }
  print gensub(":$","","g",macaddr)
  macaddr=""
}' INPUTFILE
```

does it well. [Here you can see it in action](http://ideone.com/Gd4Tp).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in plain old bash with substring extraction:

```
while read p; do
  echo ${p:0:2}:${p:2:2}:${p:4:2}:${p:6:2}:${p:8:2}:${p:10:2}
done <input.txt | tee output.txt
```