# Can I open a Genymotion device from a terminal command?

Tags: android, genymotion

When I begin my Android development I always go through the same process of opening Genymotion, then selecting a virtual device with the mouse then clicking start.

I would like to script this so I can just open the virtual device from the termainal.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not sure who down-voted this or why.  It would have been nice to leave a comment explaining why.  This seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: check out here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768489/how-to-start-genymotion-device-with-shell-command

Comment: @EJK: SO forums seem to have quite a few nitwits lately who would just downvote without giving the OP a chance to ask the question. Instead of downvoting, just close or move the question if it's off-topic. Anyway, the question asked by **ooolala** is quite valid and on-topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I script genymotion emulator to launch a given avd, headless?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396344/how-can-i-script-genymotion-emulator-to-launch-a-given-avd-headless)

Comment: I did do some searching beforehand, but didn't see the answer I was looking for.  Thanks for linking it in, this will work nicely.

Comment: This isn't working with the latest version of Genymotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396344/how-can-i-script-genymotion-emulator-to-launch-a-given-avd-headless), and here is it's accepted Answer.

For others looking for non-headless command line startup:

`/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name "xxxx"`
Get a list of vms:

`$ VBoxManage list vms
"Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 720x1280" {56d8e3aa-ecf8-483e-a450-86c8cdcedd35}`

Where xxxx can be either the name or the id:

`/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name 56d8e3aa-ecf8-483e-a450-86c8cdcedd35
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name "Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 720x1280"`

You can kill it with a normal process kill:

`ps | grep "Genymotion\.app/Contents/MacOS/player" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

**UPDATE**

Since Genymotion 2.5.0 you can manage all your Genymotion devices thanks to a command line tool. With this tool you can create, start, stop, delete, push files, flash the device, ... Here is a simple example to create a device and start it:

```
gmtool admin create "Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920" myNexus
gmtool admin start myNexus
```

This feature is available for paid licenses.

Reference Link:
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=start-virtual-devices-command-prompt#faq

Comment: This isn't working with the latest version of Genymotion.  This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768489/how-to-start-genymotion-device-with-shell-command

Comment: Thanks for Pointing this out, I have updated my Answer.